# Sum of arrays of different size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have an array, whose elements are arrays of different sizes, say:

```
[[45, 96, 0.0, 96, 96, 96, 0.0], [04, 55, 06, 55, 04, 04, 02, 55]]
```

I want to find the sum of the two arrays, i.e.,

```
[49, 151, ...]
```

Comment: Okay; did you try to solve this yourself already? If so, where did you get stuck exactly? I general, people don't respond too well to "please make this code for me"-requests (which this looks like), but **do** respond well to "I tried this and now I'm stuck/confused, please help"-requests ;-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker : True now I realized this thing.I don't know why actually people down vote  a question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
a.flat_map{|x| x.in_groups_of(a.max_by(&:size).size, 0)}.transpose.map(&:sum)
```

Or this:

```
a.max_by(&:size).map.with_index{|_, i| a.sum{|x| x[i]||0}}
```

Comment: The OP does not want a total sum of all values in both array, but the "running" sum of the two arrays.

Comment: Have you tried it? Although it's much nicer, it misses the last value in the sum (because the first array is shorter).

Comment: This works, although it is personally less comprehensible to me than my answer. I removed the downvote.

Comment: I like the second one!

Answer (score 2):

Not very pretty, but works:

```
>> a = [[45, 96, 0.0, 96, 96, 96, 0.0], [04, 55, 06, 55, 04, 04, 02, 55]]
=> [[45, 96, 0.0, 96, 96, 96, 0.0], [4, 55, 6, 55, 4, 4, 2, 55]]

>> sorted_a = a.sort_by(&:size).reverse
=> [[4, 55, 6, 55, 4, 4, 2, 55], [45, 96, 0.0, 96, 96, 96, 0.0]]

>> zipped_a = sorted_a.first.zip(sorted_a.last)
=> [[4, 45], [55, 96], [6, 0.0], [55, 96], [4, 96], [4, 96], [2, 0.0], [55, nil]]

>> zipped_a.map{ |arr| arr.map{ |v| v || 0 } }.map(&:sum)
=> [49, 151, 6.0, 151, 100, 100, 2.0, 55]
```

First you have to sort the array starting the longest for `zip` to work properly. Zipping will then create `nil` values in the redundant values of the shorter arrays. So the next step is to replace these `nil`s to zeroes (using the nested `map`) and finally you can `sum` the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way also

```
k =[]
for i in 0..ar.max_by(&:size).length-1 do
 k << ar.map { |x| [x[i]] }
end

k.map(&:flatten).map{|a| a.compact.sum}
=> [49, 151, 6.0, 151, 100, 100, 2.0, 55]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [[45, 96, 0, 96, 96, 96, 0],
     [ 4, 55, 6, 55,  4,  4, 2, 55]]

Array.new(a.max_by(&:size).size) { |i| a.reduce(0) { |t,e| t+e[i].to_i } }
  #=>[49, 151, 6, 151, 100, 100, 2, 55]
```

Note that `nil.to_i #=> 0` ([ref](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/NilClass.html#method-i-to_i)).

Another example:

```
a = [[1], [2,3,4], [5,6]]

Array.new(a.max_by(&:size).size) { |i| a.reduce(0) { |t,e| t+e[i].to_i } }
  #=> [8,9,4]
```