# How to add values of arrays having different lengths

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to add values of two different length array.

```
a =[1,2,3]
b= [1,2]
c = [1,2,3,4]
```

and so on..

I want result to be like [3,6,6,4]. How to do this in ruby on rails.

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150124/sum-of-arrays-of-different-size

Comment: @dkp I have gone through above solution but its not very smooth.I need a proper solution.

Comment: @Arslan Ali Don't change the question.

Comment: @sawa I really didn't. I just made it more self-explanatory. Your changes are welcome too.

Comment: @sawa `b` should have been `[1,2,3]`. Otherwise, the result won't be like what has been posted in question.

Comment: @ArslanAli I see. Then, I have no idea what the question was about. But notice that you are not the OP. You changed the question according to your interpretation. That is not safe to do.

Comment: @PrafullPurwar Question is not clear. What is the logic that gives that array?

Comment: @sawa : I have many arrays that are dynamic in nature. Suppose I have one array a =[1,2,3,4] , second array b=[1,2] ,third array c=[1,2,3,4,5] and so on.. I want a[i] + b[i] + c[i] + .. so on.. l want output be z=[3,6,9,8,5]. I hope it is now clear to both of you what I need.

Comment: The answer to the stated question should be`[3,6,6,4]`. Where does the 9 come from?

Comment: @PrafullPurwar Nope, not at all. I don't see how that gives you `[3, 6, 9, 4]`.

Comment: @mark: yes it will be 6, I just typed it wrong.

Comment: @PrafullPurwar edit your question to correct this.

Comment: @sawa: Please read my comments as that answer was not proper, that doesn't help me so I asked it here.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make it dynamic, I would create arrays of array with your a, b, c =>

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1, 2]
c = [1, 2, 3, 4]

arrays = [a, b, c]
```

Then I would retrieve the max size :

```
max_size = arrays.map(&:size).max #=> 4
```

Then the following line would give you your answer :

```
max_size.times.map{ |i| arrays.reduce(0){|s, a| s + a.fetch(i, 0)}}  #=> [3, 6, 6, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a new array that consists of all those array, and then can write the following code to get the array that has combined entries of each array:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]
c = [1,2,3,4]
```

Before you apply the rest of the code, you need to make sure that each array has the same length. For that, you can append `0` in all the arrays if need be, to ensure that each array has the same length as the rest of the arrays have.

```
a = [1,2,3,0]
b = [1,2,3,0]
c = [1,2,3,4]

combined_array = [a,b,c]
result = combined_array.transpose.map { |a| a.reduce :+ }
```

Comment: @arslan_ali: I have given it a try and it gives me IndexError: element size differs (4 should be 3) error.

Comment: @PrafullPurwar Yes, you need to make sure that each element has equal length. You can append zeros at the end for that case.

Comment: @arslan_ali: Thanks,I have gone through this solution and its logical and it works, is there any other way to do this other than this.

Comment: @PrafullPurwar I don't think so there would be any solution than to append `0`. You would have to assume `0` at least, otherwise you can't anything to `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Extending the answer from @Arslan Ali

I added a way to make all the arrays the same size, so that his method of summing can be applied:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]
c = [1,2,3,4]

arrays = [a, b, c]

size = [a, b, c].map{|a| a.size}.max                        # Compute maximum size
combined_array = [a,b,c].map{|a| a.fill(a.size...size){0}}  # Fill arrays to maximum size
result = combined_array.transpose.map { |a| a.reduce :+ }   # Sum everything
```

Comment: thanks it works, but it is quite long as I have all these arrays inside an array.So, I am looking for a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1, 2, 3]
c = [1, 2, 3, 4]
[a,b,c].inject([]) do |totals, add|
    add.each_with_index do |n, i|
      totals[i] = (totals[i] || 0) + n
    end
    totals
end
```